# Fatal error when POSTing an Instagram "like"

Tags: php, api, curl, error-handling, instagram

I'm working on a Instagram API Website, and I am trying to like a photo via PHP. This is my script down below. But if I call it from my browser I always get this:

**Fatal error: Function name must be a string in** in line **12**

```
<?php

    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/XXXXXxXxx_xxxxxxxxxx/likes";
    $fields = array(
        'access_token'       =>      'xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'action'             =>      'like'
    );

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$http_build_query($fields));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Line 12 is:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$http_build_query($fields));
```

and if I change:

```
....$http_build_query[$fields]);
```

the error is gone, but no output even no like posted.

Comment: Remove the $, since http_build_query is a function, not a variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is possible to call a [variable function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), PHP tries to call a function named `$http_build_query`. That variable isn't defined anywhere in your code and is `NULL`. So you'll essentially be trying to call a function whose name is *not* a string and that causes PHP to trigger a Fatal error.

Remove the `$`:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
                                     ^
```

You are also missing the `CURLOPT_URL` line in your code. The following should probably work:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: I love you @amal murali! :D